# How to add google map infowindow dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps

Here I am using Google map API to show Google map in my site. Here I am able to add google map statically by following code:

```
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(21.183008, 81.36186199999997), 6);



        var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(21.183008, 81.36186199999997), {});
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function () {
            marker.openInfoWindow("Hi ");
        });
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function () {
            map.closeInfoWindow();
        });
        map.addOverlay(marker);           


        var marker1 = new GMarker(new GLatLng(21.25, 81.62), {});
        GEvent.addListener(marker1, "mouseover", function () {
            marker1.openInfoWindow("HI All");
        });
        GEvent.addListener(marker1, "mouseout", function () {
            map.closeInfoWindow();
        });          
        map.addOverlay(marker1);
```

I have set of marker value in array. When I try it to create dynamically only last information window displayed.

awaiting for response....

Comment: This sounds like a closure problem, but where is your array (and expected `for`-loop)?

Comment: this code is from the previous version of google maps api. v3 is up for quite a time : http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html There are great sample on that page.

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle please.. i am nt sure what google map api i need to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with closures in Javascript and it is a common problem. See the [**Google Maps Javascript API Docs**](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventClosures) for a solution.

And for more information about closures I would recommend you to search on Stackoverflow (like the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop/4091780#4091780), for example) ;)