# A function inside a for loop with jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, nested, scope

i have the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i = 1; i <= number_of_banners; i++) {
    var selector = "#link_" + i;
    $(selector).click(function () {
        alert(i);
        });
    }
});
```

but the alert() can't get the "i" variable from the for loop.
How can I use the i variable of for loop inside the .click function ?

Comment: A classical one:) I guess this has been asked a dozen times on SO.

Comment: The problem you're having is that the `.click()` handlers _are_ using the `i` variable from the for loop - but all of them are referencing the same, _live_ `i` variable and by the time clicks occur the for loop has completed and `i` is equal to `number_of_banners`. (Only a dozen @Christoph? Probably at least a dozen this month...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign click handlers in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= number_of_banners; i++) {
        var selector = "#link_" + i;
        $(selector).on('click', {id: i}, function (e) {
            alert(e.data.id);
        });
    }
});
```

you should use `on` method and use click argument in it instead of using `onclick` method

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery ***[.on(event, data, handler)](http://api.jquery.com/on)*** you can do it easily.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= number_of_banners; i++) {
        var selector = "#link_" + i;
        $(selector).on('click', {id: i}, function (e) {
            alert(e.data.id);
        });
    }
});
```

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QYBjz/6/)***

Answer (score 3):

Might this happen be due the fact of the [<s>JavaScript hoisting</s>](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) JavaScript Scoping mechanism??

For instance:

- [example of wrong loop variable binding](http://jsfiddle.net/juristr/QYBjz/1/light/)

doesn't work as JavaScript uses *function scope* rather than *block scope* as we're usually accustomed from other languages like Java and C#. In order to make it work, one has to create a new scope by explicitly creating a new anonymous function which then *binds* the according variable:

- [example of correct loop variable binding](http://jsfiddle.net/juristr/QYBjz/2/)

I know this doesn't directly answer the question above, but might still be useful though for others stumbling over this question.

Comment: It's not a hoisting issue, and the scoping issues discussed in the article you link to don't really cover it either. It's more a closure issue (noting though that `i` is global in the question), and your second fiddle illustrates one way to get it to work - why don't you update your answer to talk about _why_ it works?

Comment: @nnnnnn Uhps, sorry, you're right. As I just quickly posted this answer I wrongly added the hoisting stuff, which of course is more a scoping problem (due to the JavaScript function rather than block scope) as you correctly mentioned. I'll update my answer

Comment: +1 for the second example of variable binding...... Though an answer that mentions hoisting shouldn't have var statements anywhere but on the first line of a function ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pass it as a parameter into the anonymous function as long as the function is declared within a scope that can access i.

```
function (i) {
   alert(i);
}
```

Comment: That won't work: that function is a callback for the click handler, and jQuery doesn't know to pass that `i` value in when it calls the function.

Comment: @nnn it may work if he puts the func around the handler binding and not inside.

Answer (score 1):

a quick solution would be to use the eventData and store the current `i` in that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= number_of_banners; i++) {
        var selector = "#link_" + i;
        $(selector).bind('click', i, function (e) {
            alert(e.data);
        });
    }
});
```

if you are using jquery 1.7+ then use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of bind

Comment: You can also assign a class to your banners and bind the listener to the class! I love jQuery! :D

Comment: @nmenego yeah, but the author has ids.