# JavaScript closure for jQuery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of objects each of which has a .bullet which is a SPAN.  I want to bind a click on the span to a handler than performs a certain action on the span using jQuery.  I'm seeing some behavior I don't understand, so I'm hoping someone can explain what's going on.  Basically, this first code example works:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i< length ; i++) {

            (function(){
                dataNode = dataNodeList[i];

                var handler = function(e) {

                    e.data.node.bullet.firstChild.nodeValue = "- ";


                };


                $(dataNode.bullet).on("click",{node:dataNode},handler);


            })();

        }
```

However, this second variation does not work:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i< length ; i++) {

            (function(){
                dataNode = dataNodeList[i];

                var handler = function() {

                    dataNode.bullet.firstChild.nodeValue = "- ";


                };


                $(dataNode.bullet).on("click",handler);


            })();

        }
```

In this second example,

```
dataNode.bullet.firstChild.nodeValue = "- ";
```

has no effect on the value of the SPAN I intended.  I expected dataNode.bullet to still point to the SPAN I want to change because of JavaScript closure.  So, can someone explain why this fails?  Thanks.

Comment: Two things: declare "dataNode" in that function with `var`, and pass "i" to that immediately-invoked function in the loop.  (Add "i" to its parameter list too of course.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign click handlers in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop) - this is a very common problem as the nature of the behavior involved is not obvious.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for pointing out that I forgot to declare the variable inside the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i< length ; i++) {
    (function(index){
        var dataNode = dataNodeList[index];

        var handler = function() {
            dataNode.bullet.firstChild.nodeValue = "- ";
        };

        $(dataNode.bullet).on("click",handler);
    })(i);
}
```

The closure defines a new scope. This is necessary because your handler isn't called until after the loop has finished, so `i` is not part of the scope at the time it is called, or (in some cases) has the last possible value from the loop.

Comment: This seems to have solved the main problem.  Now, at least dataNode.bullet seems to be pointing to the right span element.  Thanks for that.  I'm seeing another problem though.
dataNode.bullet.firstChild.nodeValue = "- " mysteriously just deletes the contents of the span.  However, if I immediately follow that with a line to style the span, then both changes appear.  I'm not sure if this is related to the original problem or not.

Comment: Could you explain why it was necessary to put the index parameter in the anonymous function?  I don't understand conceptually why it would make a difference and, with the important difference of delcaring dataNode inside the function, my code works without that index parameter.

Comment: @AdamCarter supplying the index as a parameter to the closure may not be strictly necessary in this case, but it certainly helps to make the code more clear.

Comment: @Shmiddty I'm pretty sure that the index parameter is required. See the difference between http://jsfiddle.net/v4sSD/ and http://jsfiddle.net/vfwnU/