# Javascript for-loop puts a pointer instead of a copy of a variable for link assignment

Tags: javascript, pointers

How super annoying is this? http://jsfiddle.net/b3xyx/

- I'm assigning a javascript function to each of my links using addEventListener.
- The loop iterates through each link, assigning an incremented variable x
- But actually when you click the links - instead of alerting the value of x, it alerts the *final* value of x; i.e. it has just assigned a pointer to x rather than copying it.
- Check it out in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/b3xyx/ clicking any of the links will alert "4". Grr.

  ```
      function goToSite(where){
          alert("This would take you to " + where + ".com")
      }

      for(var x=1; x<=3; x++){
          document.getElementById('link'+x).addEventListener('click', function(){goToSite(x)})
      }
  ```

How can I work around this? Is there a way to create a true copy of a variable in this case?

---

EDIT: Thanks for suggesting the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop), but it doesn't seem to be a duplicate.

http://jsfiddle.net/aERRE/

^ My updated code with:

```
function goToSite(whichOne){
    return function(){
        alert("This would take you to " + whichOne + ".com");
    }
}
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: Look up "JavaScript closures"

Comment: The parameter in your goToSite needs to be changed to x or the x in your alert needs to be changed to where.

Comment: Thanks storefront - changed that now. Problem still exists though.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, the for(var x...) transforms,the var x is moved to the begin of the function. and therefor the x in the goToSite refers to the global x you increased in each iteration, read about closures to understand why it happens...

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I sort of understand that its actually pointing to the same variable each time, which will be the last value of the for loop. But I'm searching for a simple solution to this that I can use in the future.

Comment: how about defining an 'onclick' function for all your links , and let it just alert the id of 'this' (the link that was clicked on?)

Comment: I would love to do this but have no idea how