# Javascript: generate dynamically handler

Tags: javascript, handler

I'm programming in Javascript.

I need to dynamically generate the event handlers for the `onclick` event.

Here above the code:

```
for (var i = 1; i < CurrValue; i++) {
    getId('btnReadRFIDTag_' + i).onclick = function () 
    {
        ReadRFIDTag(getId('txtCode_' + i));
    };

}
```

The problem, obviously is that at run time the `i` variable get the latest value and not the right value.

But I can't fix the problem, because the handler does not allow parameters for the function.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Have a good day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign click handlers in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three options:

### Use a Builder Function

The usual way is to have a builder function for the handlers:

```
for (var i = 1; i < CurrValue; i++) {
    getId('btnReadRFIDTag_' + i).onclick = buildHandler(i);
}
function buildHandler(index) {
    return function() {
        ReadRFIDTag(getId('txtCode_' + index));
    };
}
```

The function built by the `buildHandler` closes over the `index` argument from that call to `buildHandler`, rather than over `i`, and so it sees the right value.

### Use ES5's `Function#bind`

If you can rely on ES5 (or you include an ES5 shim, as this is a shimmable feature), you can do it with `Function#bind`:

```
// Using Function#bind (option 1)
for (var i = 1; i < CurrValue; i++) {
    var elm = getId('btnReadRFIDTag_' + i);
    elm.onclick = function(index) {
        ReadRFIDTag(getId('txtCode_' + index));
    }.bind(elm, i);
}
```

Used like that, it creates unnecessary extra functions, so you could also use it like this:

```
// Using Function#bind (option 2)
for (var i = 1; i < CurrValue; i++) {
    var elm = getId('btnReadRFIDTag_' + i);
    elm.onclick = myHandler.bind(elm, i);
}

function myHandler(index) {
    ReadRFIDTag(getId('txtCode_' + index));
}
```

### Use Event Delegation

Instead of putting a handler on each button, if they're all in a container (and ultimately, of course, they are, even if it's just `document.body`), you can put the handler on that container and then use `event.target` to find out which button was clicked. I wouldn't do that with old-style `onclick`, but you can with `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`:

```
var container = /* ...get the container... */;
if (container.addEventListener) {
    container.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
}
else if (container.attachEvent) {
    container.attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
       return clickHandler.call(this, e || window.event);
    });
}
else {
    // I wouldn't bother supporting something that doesn't have either
}

function clickHandler(e) {
    var btn = e.target;
    while (btn && btn !== this && btn.id.substring(0, 15) !== "btnReadRFIDTag_") {
        btn = btn.parentNode;
    }
    if (btn && btn !== this) {
        ReadRFIDTag(getId('txtCode_' + btn.id.substring(15)));
    }
}
```

The way that works is by hooking the `click` event on the container, and then when the click bubbles up (down?) to it, it looks at where the click originated and sees if that (or an ancestor of it) is one of the buttons we care about. If it is, we act on it.

Comment: While I normally wouldn't give pluses for answers to questions that have been asked a thousand times, I've got to give one for not being yet another answer that puts an IIFE in the loop... so +1. :-)

Comment: Consider adding this to the FAQs http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info (maybe adding a few words why exactly his code doesn't work).