# creating dynamic elements with jquery click event always returns last index in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
var a = {
     generateDynamicStuff: function(data) {
           for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
              var dyn_div = document.createElement('div');
              dyn_div.className = "dyn_div_"+data[i].name;
              dyn_div.textContent = data[i].name;
              document.getElementByClassName("dyn_list")[0].appendChild(dyn_div);

              $(document).on("click", ".dyn_div_"+data[i].name, function() { alert(i); a.otherFunction(i);});
           }
     },

     otherFunction: function(some_index) {....}
}
```

The idea is, I am given a list of names which I will generate clickable div elements with. When one of these divs are clicked, its index will be passed to otherFunction().

The problem is, `function() { alert(i); a.otherFunction(i);}` always gives the last index. That is, if I have 5 items, then `i` in the anonymous function is always giving me "4" no matter which div I am clicking.

Why is this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign click handlers in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop)

Comment: Not really a full answer, but I had fun creating this http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/bST4t/, which kind of does what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the [classic closure variable in a loop issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

```
var a = {
    generateDynamicStuff: function (data) {
        var $ct = $('.dyn_list');
        $.each(data, function (i, data) {
            $('<div />', {
                'class': "dyn_div_" + data.name,
                text: data.name
            }).appendTo($ct).on('click', function () {
                alert(i);
                a.otherFunction(i);
            })
        })
    },

    otherFunction: function (some_index) {....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the scope problem here click event just binds the function not execute at binding time it executes when actually event occurs at that time it takes the last value of 'i' so you can try this

```
var a = {
 generateDynamicStuff: function(data) {
       for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
          var dyn_div = document.createElement('div');
          dyn_div.className = "dyn_div_"+data[i].name;
          dyn_div.textContent = data[i].name;
          dyn_div.setAttribute("index", i);
          document.getElementByClassName("dyn_list")[0].appendChild(dyn_div);

          $(document).on("click", ".dyn_div_"+data[i].name, function(e) { 
               var index = $(this).attr("index");
               alert(index); 
               a.otherFunction(index);
          });
       }
 },

 otherFunction: function(some_index) {....}
}
```