# dynamically adding javascript eventlistener doing unexplainable things

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Currently working on a piece of code that is supposed to add eventlisteners to images on a page in a dynamical way.

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("imageBox");

function imageZoomer(imageName) {
    console.log(imageName);
}

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener("click", function(){imageZoomer(i)}, false);
}
```

However the i is showing different values then I expect. At first everything is going wel. It iterates just like it's suppose to do. But on my test page with 2 images the console log reveals '2' at both the images.

Comment: See the linked duplicates. Meanwhile, a hint: `i` is declared in one place, _outside_ the function that is called when the click occurs.

Comment: and [Assign click handlers in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4091765/218196).

Comment: Damn. Should have searched a bit further. I am sorry. Duplicates everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `i` keeps incrementing and by the time you click an image `i` is probably `images.length - 1`. You need a way to save the *current* `i` in each handler. You can store that value on each image (`images[i].index = i;` usually works) and retrieve it later but finding the object is a pain - it'd end up being something like:

```
images[i].index = i;
images[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){imageZoomer(e.target.index)}, false);
```

However, I've found the slickest way to do this is using an IIFE (read: iffy - Immediately Invoked Function Expression) to restrict the scope of `i` to whatever it was when the event was created. That looks something like:

```
images[i].addEventListener("click", (function(i){return function(){imageZoomer(i)}})(i))
```

IIFEs are super powerful. Take a look at Ben Alman's post: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: _"by the time you click an image `i` is probably `images.length - 1`"_ - No, it'll be `images.length`. Either way, do you really think a new answer was necessary when there are already three duplicate questions linked above?