# Assigning a click to elements in a looping function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm importing children of `#parentEle`, making a copy of each and pushing that copied object to array with new `ID` - `#eleCopy(i)`

I'm trying to also assign a click function to the original object imported. Clicking it would change CSS of its copy (referenced from the array). But the copy being affected is always the same one - last one loaded. I was hoping to reference it by its index number in the array... How do I "freeze" correct array reference in the click function so that `$(this)` 0 would corresponds to ar[0], $(this)` 1 to ar[1] and so on?

```
var ar = [];
var i = 0;

$('#parentEle').children().each(function() {

        ... // copy of $(this) is created: $('#eleCopy'+i)

        ar.push($('#eleCopy'+i));


        $(this).on('click', function() {

            ar[i].css({ ... });

        });

        i++;

});
```

Comment: why are you making this complex? you can assign click event separately also using event delegation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see these questions for an explanation of the problem:

- [Assign click handlers in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4091765/218196)
- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196)

In your case the solution is quite simple: Since you are already using [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), there is no need to keep an external counter. The current index is passed to the callback as argument:

```
// method signature: each( function(index, Element) )
$('#parentEle').children().each(function(i) {
    ... // copy of $(this) is created: $('#eleCopy'+i)
    ar.push($('#eleCopy'+i));

    $(this).on('click', function() {
        ar[i].css({ ... });
    });
});
```

However, the question is whether you even need to reference the clone via the array. For accessing the clone inside the event handler, you can just refer to it directly:

```
$('#parentEle').children().each(function(i) {
    var $copy = ...; // copy of $(this) is created: $('#eleCopy'+i)
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $copy.css({ ... });
    });
});
```

This works because the event handler you bind is a *closure*.

A disadvantage of both of these solutions is that you are creating a new event handler in each iteration, even though they all do the same thing. You could leverage jQuery's [`.data` API](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store a reference to the clone with the original node and bind a single event handler to the elements:

```
$('#parentEle').children().each(function(i) {
    var $copy = ...; // copy of $(this) is created: $('#eleCopy'+i)
    $(this).data('copy', $copy);
}).on('click', function() {
    $(this).data('copy').css({ ... });
});
```

Comment: the array serves other purposes also which is why I was hoping to utilize it for this purpose as well... I'm editing the question to clarify how $(this) is cloned as I'm still not getting a response on the click...

Comment: OK, but the point is that you don't have to use the array (or `i` for that matter) to refer to the cloned element.

Comment: I got you now. It actually works as your second example. I had my #eleCopy being attached to yet another dynamically created object, it was that container object that had to be set to $copy. Thank you for your help and lots of reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scope problem.

When the click event happens and `ar[i].css({ ... })` is executed, the value of i already has been incremented by all the calls to

```
i++;
```

So `i` is equal to the number of children of `#parentEle`

In order to have the desired behavior behavior, wrap the code in a closure:

Replace

```
$(this).on('click', function() {
    ar[i].css({ ... });
});
```

with

```
(function(i) {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        ar[i].css({ ... });
    });
})(i);
```

For more info about javascript closures, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/1370722)

Comment: I'll go over your reference, scope is something I need to brush up on. Your example might've actually worked on closer examination of other bits of my code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
$('#parentEle').find('[id^="eleCopy"]').each(function() {
    $(this).css({ ... });
}
```

[each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

[StartsWith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: What makes you think that the element copies are children of the same parent?