# global array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, variables, closures

I have a slideshow with button like 1,2,3,4. Also I have define an Array with 4 images url. When click the button, it call the specific corresponding url.

```
<div id="slideshow">
<div id="source"><img src="images/blue.jpg">
<ul id="controller">
<li class="button">1</li>
<li class="button">2</li>
<li class="button">3</li>
<li class="button">4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var button=document.getElementsByClassName("button")
var image=document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
var sources=new Array("images/blue.jpg","images/red.jpg","images/yellow.jpg","images/green.jpg");

for (var i=0;i<sources.length;i++){
    button[i].onclick=function(){
            image.src=sources[i]
            }
}
```

But when I click the button, the sources[i] alway return undefined.

Comment: In your case `i` variable can't be passed to event handler (onclick). You have to store its values within appropriate DOM elements

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0;i<sources.length;i++){
    button[i].onclick= function(i){
       return function(){
            image.src=sources[i]
            }
     }(i);
}
```

try this http://jsbin.com/puyipiro/1/

P.S. error cause in onclick handler i equal 4 , so must save current value on each iteration with creation handler

Comment: also I want to use this way

Comment: We pass value on each iteration into the function, so it save value in closure.

Comment: var button=document.getElementsByClassName("button")
    var image=document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
    var sources=new Array("images/blue.jpg","images/red.jpg","images/yellow.jpg","images/green.jpg");

    function changepic(x) {
      imarge.src=sources[x]
    }

    for (var i=0;i<sources.length;i++){
    button[i].onclick=changepic(i);
    }

Comment: All i recommend you look to another answers - i am also think, that it is better save image number as attribute

Answer (score 0):

You have run into one of the most confusing parts of JavaScript, the closure capture problem. To get your code to work re-write it as,

```
var button=document.getElementsByClassName("button")
var image=document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
var sources=new Array("images/blue.jpg","images/red.jpg","images/yellow.jpg","images/green.jpg");

for (var i=0;i<sources.length;i++){
   (function (i) {
     button[i].onclick=function(){
       image.src=sources[i]
     }
   })(i);
}
```

This uses a immediately executing function to introduce a new scope so each `onclick` has its own copy of `i` that has the value of `i` at the time the function was created instead of sharing the same `i` which will have the value of `sources.length`.

If you targeting a browser that supports ES 6 you can use `let` instead of `var` which will then allow you to write this as,

```
var button=document.getElementsByClassName("button")
var image=document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
var sources=new Array("images/blue.jpg","images/red.jpg","images/yellow.jpg","images/green.jpg");

for (var i=0;i<sources.length;i++){
  let j = i;
  button[i].onclick=function() {
    image.src=sources[j]
  }
}
```

The `let` statement creates a fresh scope for `j` for each iteration in the loop so the `j` captured by the `onclick` functions are different and store the value of `i` had when the function was created as the immediately executing function above does.

Unfortunately, ES 6 is not yet broadly available so some variant of my original suggestion is what you need.

Answer (score -1):

You may store `i` values within appropriate DOM elements (buttons), e.g. as attributes, then retrieving them in `onclick` handler. Somehow like this:

```
for (var i=0;i<sources.length;i++){
    button[i].setAttribute('data-btn_i', i);
    button[i].onclick=function(){
        image.src=sources[this.getAttribute('data-btn_i')];
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an expensive non-composable solution. For example, if you cut-and-pasted this code it would break as both copies would use the same attribute. You would need to remember to change the attribute name. Creating a closure is much cleaner, faster and is composable.

Comment: @chuckj expensive - maybe, non-composable - unlikely. These 2 statements are intended to be always next each to other. So I don't see how it could break anything

Comment: I understand the intent. However, it doesn't change the fact that you are using, in effect, global variables.

Comment: global variables? I think you have to read about data attributes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) before mentioning global variables

Comment: Please. I understand what an attribute is. I didn't say you used a global variable, I said you are using a technique that is equivalent to using a global variable.

Comment: A correct code fragment is not composable when it can be rendered incorrect when composed with another correct code fragment. To render yours incorrect I just need the correct code fragment `button[0].setAttribute('data-btn_i', sources.length + 1)'` Non-composability is a general property of code that uses global variables or globally accessible values, such as a DOM attribute.

Comment: This is the first time I see anyone compare HTML attribute with global variable. You might as well classify any "id" attribute (of DOM element) as global variable. In this case any JS snippet like this `document.getElementById("someform")` should be considered as deprecated. So you didn't convince me anyway.

Comment: I am not saying using a global is bad or needs to be deprecated, just that it is not composable. I don't need to convince you of a fact; it just is. As for `document.getElementById("someform")`, yes I would consider this accessing a globally accessible value. `document` is global therefore everything reachable through it is also global. My point is you shouldn't use a global, or anything like it, if a better approach is available to you.

Comment: My point is you don't understand essence of HTML attribute. If we could compare it with variable, it is more related to local variable than global. The scope of an attribute is only the HTML element it is belong to. We free to use the same named attributes in different HTML elements since they never can have collision.

Comment: I am not sure where you got the idea I don't know what attributes are or how they work. Let me assure you I do. I apparently will never make myself clear enough to be understood so I will gracefully bow out of this conversation.