# How to condense this into a single function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dry

I am really new to JS/JQuery, I cant figure out how to keep this code D.R.Y, if its even possible at all I don't know. I am using JQuery for an on hover effect with an image. Box1 being the div and the img_hover_effect being the overlay on hover.

JS:

```
$('.box1').hover(function () {
    $('.img_hover_effect').fadeIn(500);
}, function () {
    $('.img_hover_effect').fadeOut(400);
});
$('.box2').hover(function () {
    $('.img_hover_effect_2').fadeIn(500);
}, function () {
    $('.img_hover_effect_2').fadeOut(400);
});
$('.box3').hover(function () {
    $('.img_hover_effect_3').fadeIn(500);
}, function () {
    $('.img_hover_effect_3').fadeOut(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to do that.

An anonymous function inside the loop is used to prevent breakage jQuery events, try:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    (function(num){
        $('.box' + num).hover(function() {
            $('.img_hover_effect' + (num == 1 ? "" : num)).fadeIn(500)
        }, function(){
            $('.img_hover_effect' + (num == 1 ? "" : num)).fadeOut(400)
        })
    })(i)
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wZVanG/dkpokbco/)**

Comment: I have to agree with @FelixKling I am struggling to understand why this works, I know that the for loop adds to the ".box", but the "(num ==1 ? " " : num))" part i dont understand.

Comment: @Steven is a ternary operator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx. Means: IF num is equal to 1 or first item then (no add number), else add number

Comment: `num == 1 ? "" : num` is equivalent to `if (num == 1){ $('.img_hover_effect' + "") } else { $('.img_hover_effect' + num) }`

Comment: @wZVanG so where does num get its value? is it based on the for loop?

Comment: The argument `num`, it get from loop counter `})(i)`. Sorry my bad english.

Comment: @wZVanG no thank you for helping me understand, I have a ton to learn about JS and i appreciate the help

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4091780/1074519) is an example that explains what I'm doing

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think so. If there are 100 elements, looping 100 times is not tedious and slow. Also, he didn't even mention why `anynomous` function inside `for` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data` attribute on `.box` elements to store the `target` element selector.

Also, add a same class to all the `.boxn` elements to bind `event` on all the elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="mybox box" data-target=".img_hover_effect"></div>
<div class="mybox box2" data-target=".img_hover_effect_2"></div>
<div class="mybox box3" data-target=".img_hover_effect_3"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.mybox').hover(function () {
    $($(this).data('target')).fadeIn(500);
}, function () {
    $($(this).data('target')).fadeOut(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function hover(div, overlay) {
    $(div).hover(function() {
        $(overlay).fadeIn(500);
    }, function() {
        $(overlay).fadeOut(400);
    });
}
```

Then you can call it for each div and overlay as follows:

```
hover('.box1', '.img_hover_effect');
```

So you have a function which can be used for fadeIn of 500ms and fadeOut of 400ms. If you would need different fadeIn- and fadeOut-intervalls, you could even adjust the function with these as additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try combining selectors

```
$(".box1, .box2, .box3").hover(function (e) {
    $(".img_hover_effect_" + e.target.className.slice(-1)).fadeIn(500);
}, function (e) {
    $(".img_hover_effect_" + e.target.className.slice(-1)).fadeOut(400);
});
```