# JQuery - Check which button is clicked in a looped click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, for-loop

I've got a looped click function in my application something similar to

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    $("#clickedButton"+i+"").click(function()
    {
        //Code Here
    }
}
```

My issue is that I need a way to tell which button is clicked. I could just create 9 click functions but they all do the exact same thing so I figured looping it would be best. Is there a way I can tell which one is clicked. I have been able to successfully do this once like shown below

```
var i = 0;
if(i == 0)
{
    alert(i);
    $("#amount0").empty();
    amountCount[0]--;
    $("#amount0").append(amountCount[0]);
}
i++
```

When I try to add on a second if statement when it loops through on the click it changes the information in the first if statement as well. I need to be able to individually change the information and the buttons can be clicked multiple times in any order.

If any other information is needed let me know

Comment: Please read [ask]. Pay attention to the section about MCVE. Than do that. good luck.

Comment: I can't fully understand what you want to achieve, have you an example ?

Comment: Take a look at [Assign click handlers in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop) that may help.

Comment: No need for this loop in the first place, show associated html sample. This should be easily achieved using class and one click handler or an attribute selector for id

Comment: You should take a look at [event bubbling and capturing](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    $("#clickedButton"+i+"").click(function()
    {
        alert("You have clicked: ", $(this).attr('id'));            
    }
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot about using `this`. Haven't been able to fully test it out but if it works I'll accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you are assigning an `id` to each of the buttons that is pretty much identical except for the index at the end of the `id`, you could give all the buttons the same class and use the `data-` or `id` attribute for what index they represent.

**HTML**

```
<button class="myButton" data-index="0" />
<button class="myButton" data-index="1" />
...
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {
    var idx = $(this).attr("data-index");
    // You can now use the index of this button
    // where ever you need it
});
```