# How to add event listener inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason I need to loop through various elements and change their style when they are clicked. This is the code(https://jsfiddle.net/wd4z1kvs/1/) I am trying:

```js
var myscroll = {};

myscroll.list = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");

for( var j=0; j < 5; j++) {
 myscroll.list[j].anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
 myscroll.list[j].anchor.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(j);
  myscroll.list[1].anchor.innerHTML = "hello" + j;
                myscroll.list[j].anchor.innerHTML = "yellow" + j;  
 });
}
```

```html
 <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#artists">Artists</a></li>
              <li><a href="#songs">Songs</a></li>
              <li><a href="#beats">Beats</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

The problem seems to be that the event works with `j`'s present value. It doesn't take the value of the parameter when the code was actually run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign click handlers in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop)

Comment: Change `var j = 0` to `let j = 0`

Comment: @Patrick2607 That won't fix anything. That will just keep `j` from being defined outside of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var myscroll = {};

myscroll.list = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");

for( var j=0; j < 5; j++) {

  (function(j) {
  
    /* j variable is just a local copy of the j variable from your loop */

    myscroll.list[j].anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
 myscroll.list[j].anchor.addEventListener("click", function() {
 
    alert(j);
 
    myscroll.list[1].anchor.innerHTML = "hello" + j;
                myscroll.list[j].anchor.innerHTML = "yellow" + j;  
 });
    
  }(j));
  

  
  
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#artists">Artists</a></li>
              <li><a href="#songs">Songs</a></li>
              <li><a href="#beats">Beats</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

As noticed @Andreas there is a closure in a loop.

> The events don't remember values, they only keep a link (reference) to
>   the environment where they were created. In this case, the variable j
>   happens to live in the environment where the three events were
>   defined. So, all events, when they need to access the value, reach
>   back to the environment and find the most current value of j. After
>   the loop, the j variable's value is 5. So, all five events point to
>   the same value.

Comment: You should read [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/5743988)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Here, instead of just creating an event that use `j`, you pass the `j` variable's current value to immediate function. In this function, `j` becomes the local value `j`, and j has a different value every time.

Comment: The IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) creates a new closure for each value of j, so when the event handler executes, it will have access to its own copy of j

Comment: @devnull69, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), or some other looping callback function:

```
myscroll.list.forEach(function(item, j) {
    item.anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0]
                          .getElementsByTagName("li")[j]
                          .getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    item.anchor.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(j);
        myscroll.list[1].anchor.innerHTML = "hello" + j;
        item.anchor.innerHTML = "yellow" + j;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:
var myscroll = {};

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
myscroll.list = list;

for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    var anchor = list[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    anchor.setAttribute("index",j);
    myscroll.list[j].anchor = anchor;
    anchor.addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert(this.getAttribute("index"));
        this.innerHTML = "hello" + this.getAttribute("index");
        //this.innerHTML = "yellow" + this.getAttribute("index");
        this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

    });
}
```