# jQuery click() in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created `div` elements by the loop and I want to change `background-color` when I click the `div`.

```
var c = $("#container")[0];
for(var i=0; i<6;i++){
  var x = document.createElement("div");
   x.className = "sqare";
   x.click(changecolor(this));
   c.appendChild(x);
}
function changecolor(p){
  return function() {
    p.css("background-color", "yellow");
 }
}
```

I follow this [Assign click handlers in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop) , but failed...

Comment: Did you mean `x.click(changecolor(x))`?

Comment: The value of `this` will be the same for every iteration of the loop, and from the code shown it's not clear what value that is (`window`, if that code is in the global scope). Also, `x` is a DOM element, so its `.click()` method doesn't assign a click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Where `this` does not refer to the element which may refer to the `window` object instead pass the `x` as argument and [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is a jQuery method so either you need to wrap it using `jQuery` or update `style` property using JavaScript. Although attach click event by setting `onClick` property.

```
var c = $("#container")[0];
for(var i=0; i<6;i++){
  var x = document.createElement("div");
   x.className = "sqare";
   x.onClick = changecolor(p);
   c.appendChild(x);
}
function changecolor(p){
  return function() {
    p.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
 }
}
```

---

The closure can be avoided here since `this` context can be accessed within the handler.

```
var c = $("#container")[0];
for(var i=0; i<6;i++){
  var x = document.createElement("div");
   x.className = "sqare";
   x.addEvenetListener('click', changecolor);
   c.appendChild(x);
}
function changecolor(){
   this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

---

Refer : [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Comment: `x.click(changecolor(x));` won't work - a DOM element's `.click()` method doesn't assign a click handler...

Comment: @nnnnnn  : yes you are right, need to use `onClick` or `addEventListener` instead

Comment: Yep. Although the whole closure-in-a-loop thing wouldn't be necessary at all if the click handler used `this`...

Comment: @nnnnnn :  I think for that we need to use `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add event handler for each elements.

You can try to use only 1 click event.

Check my example below

SIMPLE HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var c = $("#container");
for(var i=0; i<6;i++){
    $("<div class='sqare'>hello " + i + "</div>").appendTo(c);
}

$(".sqare").on("click",function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

And live example : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/amnapc70/