# jQuery nth-child only selecting first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a on click function on the specific child of `.article` which will show certain `wikipedia` link base on the `pageid` received from the request. But all the `.article` are pointing to the same page.

**HTML:**

```
<section id="body-article">
    <div id="body-container">

    </div>
</section>
```

**JavaScript(jQuery):**

```
function SendRequest(searchEntry){
    $.ajax({
        url: `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=${searchEntry}`,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        headers: {'Api-User-Agent': 'WikiReader/0.1.0'}
      }).done(function(data, status) {
          console.log(data);
          GenerateArticle(data);
      }).fail(function(data, status) {
        console.log("ERROR! " + status);
      });
}

function GenerateArticle(data){
    //shows all the article in a div
    var totalArticleLength = data.query.search.length;
    for(var i=0;i<totalArticleLength;i++){
        var title= data.query.search[i].title;
        var pageid=data.query.search[i].pageid;
        var snippet=data.query.search[i].snippet;
        //responsible for showing single data
        CreateSingleArticle(title,pageid,snippet);
        // PROBLEM IS WITH THE BELOW LINE
        $(`.article:nth-child(${i+1})`).on("click",function(){
            window.open(`https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=${pageid}`, 'Wikipedia', 'window settings');
        })
    }

}
function CreateSingleArticle(title,pageid,snippet){
    //creates a individual data
    html =
    `<div class="article">
        <div class="side-bar"></div>
        <div class="article-container">
            <div class="article-header">
                ${title}
            </div>
            <div class="snippet">
                ${snippet}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
    $("#body-container").append(html);
}
```

Comment: For more info check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop

Comment: It's possible to scope variables within a loop: https://jsfiddle.net/amtb4t2n/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer is quite simple. You ran into javascript scope problem. Have a look at the immediate function call. Read more here. http://tobyho.com/2011/11/02/callbacks-in-loops/

```
for(var i=0;i<totalArticleLength;i++){
(function(index, pageId){

        var title= data.query.search[index].title;
        var pageid=data.query.search[index].pageid;
        var snippet=data.query.search[index].snippet;
        //responsible for showing single data
        CreateSingleArticle(title,pageid,snippet);
        // PROBLEM IS WITH THE BELOW LINE
        $(`.article:nth-child(${index+1})`).on("click",function(){
            window.open(`https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=${pageId}`, 'Wikipedia', 'window settings');
        })
})(i, data.query.search[i].pageid)
    }
```

Comment: @SadikshyaLuintel: This is a solution for former days of JS. Since you're using template literals, you might as well use other newer features, like `let i = 0;` instead of `var i = 0;` with the closure.

Comment: To all downvoters. Please leave a message why you have down voted this post. This helps me to improve my self.

Comment: @SadikshyaLuintel rock star answer is the newer solution which you should prefer. Haven't recognized that you are using newer ecmascript.

Comment: With the scoping, I don't think the `nth-child` specific part is needed anymore, since `pageId` will be scoped with the appropriate iterated row. Just make it react on `.article` click.